# How can I loop with different number of slides (controller-slider + slider)?

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

How to implement infinite scrolling functionality on the first slider if it is controlled by the second one, and the number of slides is different?

I mean, for example: to have 2 slides on the first slide rotating infinitely, and any number of slides on the second slide, but not infinite.

The first thing i tried, of course, was to use
**loop: true**, but of course I got no result. In the controller there is a specific binding to the index of both slides and because of that the slides are "jumping"

Look on Demo: https://codepen.io/RomanSydor/pen/abaYvod

```js
// initialize first swiper
const slider = new Swiper('.myslider', {
  loop: true,
  createElements: true,
  effect: 'flip',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  allowTouchMove: false,
  observer: true,
  mousewheel: true,
  observeParents: true,
  on: {
    slideChange: function() {
      console.log(slider.realIndex);
    },
  },
});

// initialize second swiper
const control = new Swiper('.controller', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  grabCursor: true,
  touchEventsTarget: '.slider-container',
  allowTouchMove: true,
  observer: true,
  mousewheel: true,
  observeParents: true
});

// synchronize swipers
control.controller.control = slider;
```

```css
.slider-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #afafaf;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  gap: 45px;
}

.slider-container .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myslider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.myslider .swiper-slide {
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.controller {
  color: #bd67f4;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.1.0/swiper-bundle.css" integrity="sha512-6HEJkWR1zijwiB3XwQE9eHjDBJmA/Fcl88LlxMba1EC1kakrlXOA14rJmQujhDkTQ6/TSXmGo0w57GbnZ2FSdQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="swiper-slider myslider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: plum;">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: orange;">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: orangered;">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slider controller">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: aqua">Controller 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: aquamarine;">Controller 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: greenyellow;">Controller 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: gold;">Controller 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color: navajowhite;">Controller 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.1.0/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-sR63/L3Slqn0OWMMafv7gmRGxkYJOcfgdN3jznwea9NYiett6R+cGdZ0t0TRHeH1gZogMyLE1oQpQ0Lc6ULKbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```